# How to convert ngModel string to date?

Tags: angular

I use Material datepicker:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input
        matInput
        [required]="fieldDefinition.required"
        [matDatepicker]="dateDocumentStart"
        [(ngModel)]="fieldDefinition.fieldvalue"
        (focus)="dateDocumentStart.open()"
    />

    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateDocumentStart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dateDocumentStart></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

As you can see I use `[(ngModel)]="fieldDefinition.fieldvalue"` to apply date.

The `fieldDefinition.fieldvalue` has string value "12.05.1976". How to convert it to date type in specific format?

I have tried to apply a custom pipe:

```html
[(ngModel)]="fieldDefinition.fieldvalue | mycustompipe"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a pipe is the good way.

Instead of using a custom pipe, you can use the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) of Angular.

There is a `format` parameter customization.

Comment: Could you sahre a full example , how to apply this to datepicker in component?

Comment: Why I can not use a custom pipe?

Comment: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 13 in [dateValue | date: 'dd.mm.YYYY'=$event]

Comment: I can't program right now, so I can't share a full example. For your error, try `[ngModel]="fieldDefinition.fieldvalue | date" (ngModelChange)="fieldDefinition.fieldvalue = $event"`. You absolutely can use a custom pipe but since you want to display a date, I think it was easier to just use the prebuild DatePipe.

Comment: `DatePipe` or `date`?